# Error bundling: gem "depends on activesupport (= 3.0.0)" where app "depends on activesupport (4.0.0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In a gem, I specified `spec.add_dependency "active_support"`, but when I add my gem to a Rails 4 project and `bundle`, I get a weird error:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    my_gem (>= 0.0.5) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (4.0.0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change it to `spec.add_dependency "activesupport"` without the underscore. Presumably there are gems out there by the old name but that only go up to 3.0.0.